# Find isomorphism between $S_3$ and $GL_2(F_2)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, determinant

Find isomorphism between $S_3$ and $GL_2(F_2)$.

proof: Let $A = \begin{pmatrix}
 a& b\\ c
 & d
\end{pmatrix}$. Where $\det (A) \neq 0$.

And recall $S_3$ is the permutation group with {1,2,3}.

Then there are $6$ different matrices Let $ \begin{pmatrix}
 1& 1\\ 1
 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ ,  $ \begin{pmatrix}
 1& 1\\ 0
 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$ ,  $ \begin{pmatrix}
 0& 1\\ 1
 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$ ,  $ \begin{pmatrix}
 1& 0\\ 1
 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$ , $ \begin{pmatrix}
 1& 0\\ 0
 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$ , $ \begin{pmatrix}
 0& 1\\ 1
 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ .
And $|GL_2(F_2)| = 6$.
And $|S_3| = 3! = 6$
both have orders $6$.

I was trying to construct a map by trying to compare their Cayley tables, but in general matrix multiplication does not commute. Can someone please help me? Maybe we can construct a map, but I am not sure. 
I am stuck.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Note that there is only one non-abelian group of order 6 (which is $S_3$). You can also see the answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/567045/prove-gl-2-mathbbz-2-mathbbz-is-isomorphic-to-s-3)

Comment: How many elements are there in $(F_2)^2\setminus \{0\}$?

Comment: Following  @user24142 comment. You know that $\mathbb{F}_2^2$ is a vector space and $(0,0)$ is fixed by any isomorphism (which, in turn is permuting the other elements..).

Answer (score 1):

Observe that every element of $S_3$ can be written in terms of $\alpha=(1 \, 2)$ and $\beta=(1 \, 2\, 3)$. Also observe that $|\alpha|=2$ and $|\beta|=3$. Now look for matrices in $GL(\mathbb{Z}_2)$ which have orders $2$ and $3$ respectively. Suppose they are $A$ and $B$. Then consider the function $f(\alpha)=A$ and $f(\beta)=B$. Extend it (using the homomorphic property) to create an isomorphism.