# Show that Symmetric Group $S3$ and $GL(n,\mathbb F_2)$ is an isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, group-isomorphism, vector-space-isomorphism

Show that Symmetric Group $S3$ and $GL(n,\mathbb F_2)$ is an isomorphism.

$\mathbb F_2$ has $2$ elements - $0,1$.

In $GL(n,\mathbb F_2)$ there are $2$ choices for each entry so $8$ possible matrices in total.

But the symmetric group $3$ has order $6$. The cycles are:

$[],[1,2],[1,3],[2,3][1,2,3],[1,3,2]$

How can I show that they are isomorphic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we should remark that the claim is only true for $n=2$.
By Cauchy's Theorem, any group of order $2p$ with $p$ prime is either isomorphic to the cyclic group $C_{2p}$, or to the dihedral group $D_p$.
For $p=3$ we obtain that there are exactly $2$ non-isomorphic groups of order $6$, namely the cyclic group $C_6$, and the group $D_3=S_3$. Since your group
$GL(2,\mathbb{F}_2)$ is not abelian, hence not cyclic, it must be isomorphic to $S_3$.

Edit: I just saw that the question has been answered already; this answer is perhaps also useful, so I will leave it here.

Comment: thanks, I don't understand how $GL(2,F_2)$ has order 6? Do I need to check that if $A \in GL(2,F_2) \Rightarrow A^3=A, A^2=A$ or $A=A$

Comment: Just list all $2\times 2$ matrices $A$ with $\det(A)\neq 0$ with coefficients $0,1$ and the rule $2=0$. There are exactly $6$ such matrices, listed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419268/find-isomorphism-between-s-3-and-gl-2f-2?lq=1).